# JS file shows "undefined" when trying to find a value from JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code which shows a testing login page:

```js
const port = 3012;
app.use(express.static('public'));
let urlencodedParser = express.urlencoded({extended: true});
let count = 0; // Visit count
let startDate = new Date(); // Server start Date time

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
     //res.send(`Current Date/Time: ${curDate.toLocaleString()}, Server Up Since: ${startDate.toLocaleString()}`);
    res.render('login.njk');
})
app.post('/loggedin', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("You logged in");
    let uname = req.body.uname;
    var found = database.find(function (element) {
        return element.email === req.body.uname;
    });
    console.log(found);

})

host = '127.0.0.1';
```

with a json value with test accounts, one of the values containing this.

```json
{
        "firstName": "Melia",
        "lastName": "Barker",
        "email": "tirrivees1820@outlook.com",
        "password": "hhQcH0PVgMpQq6ve",
        "role": "admin"
    },
```

EDIT: Here is the NJK code with the uname part.

```
        <form action="./loggedin" method="post">
            <b><p id="signin" align="center"></p></b>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="uname" name="uname"><br>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="signinbutton">
        </form>
```

I run the JS code and go to the address for the login page, and type the following email and password out. However, when I try to run the code, the node.js program shows the JSON email and password, but then "undefined" instead of the email. How can I fix my find function to make the console show the email?

Comment: There is no `uname`? Is there a typo?

Comment: Forgot to mention that uname part is from an njk file linking to the login page. Will edit that code in the question.

Comment: I think you should set a breakpoint at the database select section from your developer tool and take a look.

Comment: convert `uname` to `email`

Comment: Uname is the name of the email part in my form, so I can't change it to email. Also, how do I set a breakpoint in my database select section?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I just found out that I was using the wrong JSON file for the database variable, and I changed it, and it worked this time. To everyone who tried to post an answer or a reply, I apologize for the inconvinience.